# How to disable timeout of password prompt for partition decryption during boot?

Tags: boot, opensuse, password, encryption, timeout

I have a computer running OpenSUSE 12.1, 64-bit, default install.

How it works currently:

1. I turn on the computer
2. It goes through the boot process
3. At some point during boot, I am asked for password to decrypt an encrypted partition

The problem is there is a timeout on this prompt, so I have to sit next to computer and pay attention to what is going on.

How can I disable that timer, so I could for example turn the computer on and go away, and then return after 1 hour and still see this prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [this Opensuse forum thread](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/472714-how-disable-timeout-password-entry-encrypted-home-partition.html).  It reveals that it's an issue with `systemd`'s default unit timeout and not respecting the `timeout` setting in `crypttab`.

[It also provides a workaround -- letting the initrd take care of it](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/472714-how-disable-timeout-password-entry-encrypted-home-partition-2.html#post2444037), with an `/etc/crypttab` entry like this (i.e. adding the `initrd`)

```
cr_sdb3         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SHORTENED-part3 none       initrd
```

followed by rebuilding with `mkinitrd`.

Additionally, the author of the linked post filed [a bug report](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=749706).

Comment: Somehow I missed the execution of `mkinitrd`. Thank you a lot.